# How to change a variable inside view via template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have this function which is passed in context in the class based view

## views.py

```
def date_range():
    week = 0
    if week >= 0:
        week = int()
    elif week < 0:
        pass

    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    return [start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range(11 + week)]


class MyListView(ListView):
    [...]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            [...]
            'date_range': list(date_range()),
        })

        return context
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'my_app.views.date_range', name='date_create'),
    url(r'^$', views.MyListView.as_view(), name='people'),
)
```

## template

```
    <a href="{% url my_app.views.date_range week|add:'-11' %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
    <a href="{% url my_app.views.date_range week|add:'11' %}">Next &gt;&gt;</a>
```

As you can see I want to change 'week' variable whenever I click on the link << Previous and Next>>

I'm doing this [tutorial](http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/cal1.html)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I got 

`Reverse for '' with arguments '(u'-11',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: You haven't got any variable called "week" in your context.

Comment: I added `week = 0` oustide function then in context `'week': week`
And I got same error

Comment: I just edited my urls.py and add tutorial I'm currently doing

Answer (score 0):

Inside your url tag you have to use the name of your url.

You should read the django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

The correct syntax would be:

```
{% url 'date_create' arg=11 %}
```

### update

I checked your tutorial, first you need to update your view:

```
def date_range(request, week=None):
```

Sorry my bad your url was half good I didn't understand what you were trying to do this should work.

```
{% url 'date_create' week|add:'11' %}
```

Comment: I still got `Reverse for 'date_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'arg': -11}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['my_app/(\\d+)/$']`

Comment: If I updated my view, then `'date_range': list(date_range())` in context won't work, because it takes no arguments.